# Where was this picture of Squamish, BC captured?

Tags: identify-this, locate-this, british-columbia

Can I access, by private car, the location where [the photo below](https://redd.it/4u093i) was captured?

[image]

Comment: @Canada-Area51Proposal: You should attribute the photograph to its author, by name, in your post. A link to a reddit thread is insufficient.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit to be fair, the name isn't in the reddit thread either, as far as I can see...

Comment: @MarkMayo: I think we can hold ourselves to a higher standard than Reddit :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit sure, but have you tried looking? Even my checking for the image - it seems like the reddit post was genuinely the original source.  So if he didn't say who he was, we likely can't.

Comment: @MarkMayo: Then a notation that "source is unknown" will at least show that a fair effort was made :) (I agree that this one is tough - the best _I_ can do is "Reddit user Strobless's dad"!) My concern is that no permission was given to reproduce the image here, though admittedly I don't know the ins and outs of Reddit's licensing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit given it was posted by /u/Strobless and attributed to his father, surely that'd be a better attribution than 'unknown'?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - the only thing I'm aware of the licensing is that reddit gets a fairly open lisc for themselves (and they can then auth people) but the content ownership still lies with the poster. See: https://www.reddit.com/help/useragreement#p_17

Comment: @tanantish: That was a response to "if he didn't say who he was" - as you point out, we _do_ have a name to work with here.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I found these six landmarks in the image that lined up nicely with each other:

[image: Landmarks]

Then I created [a map](https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=1lf6KFC2YdGX428_gelNRZ24Dh4A&ll=49.72039851875357%2C-123.10526272992911&z=12) where I found roughly the coordinates of these landmarks, and drew lines straight through them:

[image: Map with lines]

As you can see, these three lines intersect nicely at a [single point](https://www.google.no/maps/place/49%C2%B044'45.3%22N+123%C2%B003'22.2%22W/@49.742495,-123.0842145,13.79z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d49.74592!4d-123.05616) (at approximately 49.746°N 123.056°W, marked in yellow), which should be approximately the location the image was taken.

Comment: WOW. That's a research to do :)

Comment: Well I'm glad we both came up with Round Mountain, but I tip my hat to your more scientific research style :)

Answer (score 22):

[As near as I can tell, it's taken from about here](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@49.7705055,-123.0430639,274a,20y,219.97h,82.97t/data=!3m1!1e3?hl=en) (note that the perspective is different in Google maps to the photo - presumably imitating a different width lens) :

[image]

Which would appear to be the view from roughly Round Mountain, looking SW over Squamish.

Google Maps is a bit fiddly, but you can use your mouse to move around in 3D.

It's hike-able, and is estimated to take about [4.5 hours round trip](http://www.straight.com/article-773571/vancouver/round-mountain-hike-samples-garibaldi-provincial-parks-delights) to the top.  There's no road access.